# How to login into ssh on windows cmd prompt

Tags: windows, ssh, cmd

I am trying to login into one of the ethernet ports on my development board on ssh from my Windows pc. But it is displaying a message like

'ssh' is not recognized as an internal or external command when i tried to loging into it using ssh root@192.168.4.14.

How to get ssh into my windows system?

Comment: try using [putty](http://www.putty.org/) or [mobaxterm](http://mobaxterm.mobatek.net/)

Answer (score 1):

I use Linux Bash on my windows to use ssh. 
You can install it from your windows configurations. But I think it is only for Windows 10 64bits. 
Or if you want, you can install git desktop application. From this you can use linux commands into the git bash.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below command in command prompt to initiate ssh session.
ssh -l username 192.168.1.1

Comment: You can send your answer as a comment.